# subtract 6 hours from wordpress get_the_time

Tags: php, wordpress, subtraction

I am trying to subtract a certain amount of hours from the wordpress function get_the_time(); so the post looks like that is been posted before.

this is the code I have:

```
<?php  function displaytime() {
return get_the_time(strtotime( '-6 hours' ) );
}
        echo displaytime(); ?>
```

the problem is that the output is now : 1506910342

can someone help me out?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in [docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_time), first param for `get_the_time` function is date format and it returns string in your specified format. So instead you can use `U` as a first parameter, so you will get UNIX time, then subtract 6 hours using [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php), and format it again with [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function:

```
 date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-6 hours', (int)get_the_time('U')));
```

Comment: solved, thank you very much for your help guys hefe is the code I used :

`<?php  
    $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-6 hours', (int)get_the_time('U')));
   echo $date;
?>`

Answer (score 1):

1506910342 is a unix time stamp.

You can simply use [this](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimestamp.php) method to get a datetime from a unix time stamp

For example:

```
$ts = get_the_time(); 
$ts -= 6 * 60 * 60;
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setTimestamp($ts);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I set the time correctly now, but it doesn't subtract the 6 hours from the time, here is the code '<?php  function displaytime() {
    return get_the_time(strtotime( 'U = Y-m-d H:i:s', '-6 hours' ) );
}
 
   echo displaytime(); ?>'

Comment: You need to subtract the seconds from the timestamp instead of the '-6 hours'. For six hours this would be 21600. You could also use 6 * 60 * 60

Comment: sorry, I am very new in php, so instead of '-6 hours' I have to set '-21600' ?

Comment: In your question you have the following statement return get_the_time(strtotime( '-6 hours' ) ); and you said that it would return you a timestamp. You now only need to substract 21600 from the timestamp. See my answer, I've edtied it!

Comment: for example... ? :-)